# Web crawler for django app; should I write it in django or as separate script

Tags: python, django, web-crawler

I have Django app just for CRUD of some daily data.
Model only have price and date.

I should write some code that will automatically(daily) insert new data to my model.

I am planning to use [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) for web page parsing.

So I have few questions:

1. I am planing to use crontab (manual edit with crontab -e) for setting task to run once daily. Is there smarter solution ?
2. Should I use Django ORM or just write SQL in separate script ?

I am looking for advices what is better in the long run. I will have more task like this one.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are already building supporting code in Django for your models and will be running the code on the same server your app is installed on, then you should probably use Django ORM.

See this page for help getting started writing command-line admin utilities that get run in the context of your Django app:

- https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-management-commands/

Comment: +1 A custom ./manage.py command invoked from cron is probably the simplest approach

Comment: If I understand you correctly, your suggestion is to make custom django-admin command (like updateDBFromWeb) and then call it via crontab ?

Answer (score 1):

This answer is more a general architecture answer...

To start, everything can be done in django.

I would set up celery and periodic tasks: http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/periodic-tasks.html

For the actual crawl, you will probably need to fan out on link discovery... you can use celery for that too using just the @task decorator.

Start the project using the django:/// broker. Once you get to size, move on to RabbitMQ.

Comment: Thank you on your answer, I learned some thing new. For my current requirements "custom ./manage.py command" looks more easy to implement.

Comment: True - but in the long term, learning Celery would increase your value as a developer immensely.